# moderncv doesn't compile with email, homepage or phone

Tags: moderncv

I want to use moderncv package, however I have some problem with it:
if I use a standard example, it doesn't produce any pdf, however there are no errors... If I remove fields like email, homepage, phone and leave there only address and name/surname, it works.

I use MacTex...

any ideas?

Comment: I think you need the `MarvoSym` package for the little email symbols etc. (I'm going on memory here. Check the log)

Comment: marvosym package is installed, even if I use \usepackage{marvosym} it doesn't work...

Comment: Are there any obvious problems in the log file? Do you have the most up to date versions of each package?

Comment: well there is some file missfont.log with lines similar to: mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+264/600 --dpi 864 umps
in standard log I can't see nothing, just some warnings like:
Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfpagelabels' is turned off
(hyperref)                because \thepage is undefined.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/lmss/m/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/lmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 51.

Comment: well, there appeared Font umvs at 864 not found,kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+264/600 --dpi 864 umvs
gsftopk: fatal: map file `cid-base.map' not found.
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for umvs.
mktexpk: perhaps umvs is missing from the map file.

Comment: @morph: You can add such logs to your question, they'll be easier to read there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: re-install MarvoSym package (it updates all the fonts during the reinstall) and now it works